# What is the whitespace indicated with a dot in TextMate?

Tags: macos, textmate, whitespace

In the screenshot of TextMate below, I turned on "Show Invisibles." What's the whitespace character on the third line?

Text I imported from somewhere has these dot spaces, and I'm trying to figure out what they are.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

In contrast to normal spaces, they won't cause a line break. For example, you may want to add one between "OS" and "X" when you write "OS X". In HTML, they're created through the `&nbsp;` character reference, but you can type them on a Mac by pressing ⌥-Space.

To inspect them, just copy them to *Character Viewer*'s search box (press ⌥⌘T):

[image]

Whether you want them or not depends on your application. Some compilers might chocke on these non-ASCII characters, for example. It's generally better to replace them with normal spaces unless you really need them.

Comment: Thanks @slhck. That was it-- they were ignored by pdflatex and replacing them with normal spaces fixed the problem.

Comment: I know what you mean! Had these problems with LaTeX myself, resulting in weird errors.